# Como não enviar arquivos Target

Tags: eclipse, svn

Quando do Syncronize no meu projeto no `SVN` ele aparece uma lista gigante com os arquivos do `Target` onde se eu tentar dar *commit* da erro.

Tem como fazer o SVN ignorar esses arquivos?

Estou usando o SVN do Eclipse.

Comment: Você está tendo problemas com o `svn:ignore` Ou não conhece esse recurso?

Comment: @bigown A opção aparece desabilitada tanto no meu pc quanto no pessoal da minha equipe.

Comment: Não conheço o Eclipse mas posso tentar lhe dar uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço o Eclipse mas acho que deve fazer isto manualmente na linha de comando:

```
svn propset svn:ignore Target .
```

`svn:ignore` é a propriedade que faz o que você quer.

Use `propedit` se precisa mudar.

Se quiser ignorar certos tipos de arquivos e não uma pasta:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.txt" .
```

Comment: Mas esse comando executo na minha maquina ou no servidor?

Comment: Em geral na sua máquina. É possível usar no servidor também, mas não parece ser o seu caso.

Comment: Vou testar aqui.

Comment: consegui executar, mas fala que o meu svn esta em uma versão antiga, e que tenho que baixar uma nova.
daqui ja consigo me virar, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas como precisei agora e consegui achar a resposta, gostaria de deixar registrado para pesquisa futura.

Pode-se incluir as pastas que não se deseja enviar para o `SVN` no Eclipse em `Windows` → `Preference` → `Team` → `Ignored Resources`.

Clique em `AddPattern` e digite `target` ou o nome da pasta desejada.